# Substrate Offchain-worker Http Fetch Error

Tags: substrate

### Problem

- I want to get data from Github using Substrate's Offchain-worker.
- The following sample works.
- However, when I change the URL to Github, I get an error with the "pending.try_wait" function.
- I'm adding it because I need a "User-Agent" to send an Http Request to Github.
- If anyone knows why this fails, could you please tell me?

### Successful sample

```
        let deadline = sp_io::offchain::timestamp().add(Duration::from_millis(2_000));
        let request =
            http::Request::get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD");
        let pending = request.deadline(deadline).send().map_err(|_| http::Error::IoError)?;
        let response = pending.try_wait(deadline).map_err(|_| http::Error::DeadlineReached)??;
        if response.code != 200 {
            log::warn!("Unexpected status code: {}", response.code);
            return Err(http::Error::Unknown)
        }
```

### Sample to fail

```
        let deadline = sp_io::offchain::timestamp().add(Duration::from_millis(2_000));
        let request =
            http::Request::get("https://api.github.com/orgs/substrate-developer-hub");
        let pending = request
            .add_header("User-Agent", "SampleAgent")
            .deadline(deadline).send()
            .map_err(|_| http::Error::IoError)?;
        let response = pending.try_wait(deadline).map_err(|_| http::Error::DeadlineReached)??; -> ### Error is Occuered.
        if response.code != 200 {
            log::warn!("Unexpected status code: {}", response.code);
            return Err(http::Error::Unknown)
        }
```

Comment: Maybe view my sample code again? emm

Comment: https://github.com/saintfeng/slides/blob/30e03ae7c603187b118a32c8b376969479b1b5ac/04-ocw/ocw-example/pallets/ocw/src/lib.rs#L510-L544

Comment: Your sample also encountered an error in the same place.

Comment: code of that part came from Jimmy who gave a lesson of ocw. it worked well before. Are you sure u can request a user-agent of "sampleagent"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I changed the User-Agent to "jimmychu0807" and ran it as in the sample, but I got the same error in the same place.

Comment: hmm, i've no idea. maybe u should paste detailed error info so other real technic guys could help you.